# Website Multiple File Upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Hi I'm very new to web development but have a coding background. I'm trying to create a very simple multiple file uploader for a form i'm creating however i cannot for the life of me get it to work. I followed a tutorial i found online and here is what i have so far. I am getting the hmm echo ha

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" onChange="makeFileList();" />
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <p>
        <strong>Files You Selected:</strong>
    </p>
    <ul id="fileList"><li>No Files Selected</li></ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeFileList() {
            var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
            var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
            while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
                ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = input.files[i].name;
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
            if(!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = 'No Files Selected';
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?PHP
if(count($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'])) {
  foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'] as $file) {
    move_uploaded_file($file, "uploads/" . "sample.png" );
  }
}else{
echo "hmm";
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

Okay i updated the php file to this and originally had an echo in which echoed my files correctly however i can't get the actual upload to happen now i just want to add the file to my upload directory which i've set permissions on already to be 777 with filezilla and want to keep the same name of the file

```
<?PHP
if(count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'])) {
  foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'] as $file) {
    move_uploaded_file($file, "uploads/" . $file );
  }
}else{
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for the help so far!

Comment: I'm getting the hmm echo so it's not looping and uploading each file i just don't really understand why is the thing since i just followed the tutorial and i'm very new to php. I'm assuming the if statement is checking that there are files to be uploaded and the array isn't empty

Comment: what does print_r($_FILES); return ?

Comment: Array ( [filesToUpload] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Sourceryv2.1.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phphYLOt5 ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 1041863 ) ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
    count($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'])
```

Will always return zero, as that element does not actually exist in the $_FILES array.

It may be more helpful to "print_r()" your $_FILES array in the event of an error (in test only). Here is an example of the multi-file upload syntax.

```
    Array
    (
        [filesToUpload] => Array
            (
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test.txt
                        [1] => test - Copy.txt
                    )

                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => text/plain
                        [1] => text/plain
                    )

                [tmp_name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3770.tmp
                        [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3771.tmp
                    )

                [error] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                    )

                [size] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
```

Using count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name']) should be the fix for your script.

**EDIT**

With your code

```
    if(count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'])) {
      foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'] as $file) {
        move_uploaded_file($file, "uploads/" . $file );
      }
    }
```

You are sending the name (['name'] (which is an array element) as $file), which doesn't translate, as the move_uploaded_file() is looking for the tmpname (or filepath) of the uploaded file. You can change what you have to this.

```
    if(count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'])) {
      foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'] as $ref => $fullfilename) {
        move_uploaded_file($fullfilename, "uploads/" . $_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$ref] );
      }
    }
```

This will get you in the ballpark, but I have to mention, that there are much better ways of handling this. I will try and post a class I have for multi-file upload (or find one on Google) and link it to comment on this page. But the above, should get you (at a bare minimum) what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks much closer could you please see my edit and help me with why uploading isn't actually happening

Comment: Please see the edit above to address your second question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks a ton and yea would love to see the better ways of doing it i just need real simple for now but always looking to learn more